# What's the meaning of the letter ‘v’ in setvbuf()?

Tags: c

Recently, I found two functions [`setbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setbuf) and [`setvbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf) can be used to set stream buffer. What's the meaning of the letter `v` in the name `setvbuf`? Is it `various`, `version` or something else?

Comment: According to _C: A Reference Manual_ by Harbison and Steele, "The function `setvbuf` is the more general function adopted from UNIX System V." (370) I'm not sure if this is where the "v" originally came from, but it is suggestive.

Comment: @ex nihilo, I didn't know that bit of history, but that was my first guess :) wee! Got lucky, hehe You should make that an answer. You could literally post it as-is.

Comment: @ikegami -- done. I didn't post as an answer at first because it is really conjecture on my part, but I do suspect that this is the answer. If someone comes along with a better story or better references, I'll update or delete ;)

Comment: @exnihilo This is certainly correct history but it doesn't actually explain what the V actually means. If you're suggesting that 'V' means 'System V' you're certainly wrong. It was `setvbuf()` *in* System V.

Comment: @user207421 -- I looked in a System V reference manual from 1985 and saw no `setvbuf`, but only `setbuf`; then I looked in the 1988 edition of the same reference and saw that `setvbuf` had been added. Ah well, I did say that this was _conjecture_; answer deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found any explanation of 'v' anywhere but I guess it may be 'variable' since it allows to specify the size and mode of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

V is either variable or value probably in accordance with the context. As we know, the function of setbuf() has no returned value, so the unix system designer has assigned the v(value) to differentiate setvbuf() and setbuf(). This function returns zero on success else, non-zero value is returned. Please see the the following descriptions.

**1.IBM**

General description
Controls the buffering strategy and buffer size for a specified stream. The stream pointer must refer to an open file, and setvbuf() must be the first operation on the file.

```
Value
    Meaning
_IONBF
    No buffer is used.
_IOFBF
    Full buffering is used for input and output. Use buf as the buffer and size as the size of the buffer.
_IOLBF
    Line buffering is used for text stream I/O and terminal I/O. The buffer is flushed when a newline character is used (text stream), when the buffer is full, or when input is requested (terminal). The value for size must be greater than 0.
```

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-setvbuf-control-buffering

**2.informatik(hamburg.de)**

DESCRIPTION:

Use setvbuf to specify what kind of buffering you want for the file or stream identified by fp, by using one of the following values (from stdio.h) as the mode argument:

```
_IONBF
Do not use a buffer; send output directly to the host system for the file or stream identified by fp.

_IOFBF
Use full output buffering; output will be passed on to the host system only when the buffer is full, or when an input operation intervenes.

_IOLBF
Use line buffering; pass on output to the host system at every newline, as well as when the buffer is full, or when an input operation intervenes.
```

[https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/~krabat/FH-Labor/gnupro/4_GNUPro_Libraries/a_GNUPro_C_Library/libcsetvbufspecify_file_or_stream_bu.html](https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Ekrabat/FH-Labor/gnupro/4_GNUPro_Libraries/a_GNUPro_C_Library/libcsetvbufspecify_file_or_stream_bu.html)